# downsides of setting systemd journal storage to volatile

Tags: raspbian

I'm used to using the log files in /var/log/, and I never use journalctl; what if anything would be broken if I were to disable the systemd journal persistence by setting /etc/journald.conf storage=volatile? Background: I'm trying to reduce disk activity by storing the journal in memory only.

Comment: If you crash, you lose your journal which could make some specific situations difficult to troubleshoot if the crash tied into a program which logs to journald. More or less the same risks as any volatile storage method; no power = its gone.

Comment: but wouldn't those logs already be written to disk by rsyslog already? that is to say, is there anything important that writes only to the systemd journal?